# ggplot problem with stat_summary connecting different groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with 5 columns:
1: names of entities
2: category: factor with 13 levels
3: condition: factor with 2 levels
4: status: factor with 4 levels
5: values

My purpose is to plot the medians of the values corresponding to the 13 categories across the 4 status, with two lines that connects the 4 status medians for each of the 2 conditions

I am using this code:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=status, y=values, color=condition)) +
  stat_summary(fun = median,
               geom  = "line",
               group = 1, aes(color=condition)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ category)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tiEB.jpg)
It works OK except that it connects the two lines; after the 4th status of the 1st condition it draws a line back to the 1st status of the 2nd condition.

What I need is two fully separated lines...

Comment: If you want lines by condition then remove `group = 1`and try `aes(group=condition)` in the `stat_summary` layer. Also. You don't need to map category a second on color.

Comment: so simple. thank you very much stefan - much appreciated